# GraphQl Variable Question - hardcode works

Tags: api, post, graphql, postman

I am wondering why my 2nd postman request does not work when utilizing variables for graphql api POST request.

The 1st request below works on Postman.
Variables with graphql issue.

```
query {getById(id: "2"){
  id 
  name
  icon
  elements {
    id name link
    elements {
      id name link
      elements {
        id name link
        elements {
          id name link
            }
        }
    }
  }
} }
```

```
query {getById($id: String ){
  id ($id: id)
  name
  icon
  elements {
    id name link
    elements {
      id name link
      elements {
        id name link
        elements {
          id name link
           }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }

} }
```

variable

```
{
    "id": "2"
}
```

Comment: bad syntax [and probably arg type - see API specs] - https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Answer (score 0):

Your second postman request is not working because you're not having the node called "2" in the graphQL definition.

A simple breakdown of your request:

```
query {getById(id: "2"){
```

Above identifies the item with id 2 from the service.
All below that method are just nodes that you want to retrieve.

Also I think you can just use below:

```
query {getById($id: String ){
  id 
  name
  icon
  elements {
    id name link
    }
}
```